# How to find the address of a local variable and display its value from a disassembled function from a core dump

Tags: debugging, assembly, linux-kernel, coredump, panic

I am using the crash utility to investigate a core file dump. From this core dump, I can see that one processes has two deadlocked threads. The cause of the deadlock seems to be `task->mm->mmap_sem` being held for way too long while trying to serve a page fault. I am trying to figure out the faulting address that caused this issue.

While serving a page fault, the Linux kernel function `do_page_fault` reads the fault address from `cr2` register and then proceeds to server the page fault. See code below.

```
dotraplinkage void __kprobes
do_page_fault(struct pt_regs *regs, unsigned long error_code)
{
    struct vm_area_struct *vma;
    struct task_struct *tsk;
    unsigned long address;
    struct mm_struct *mm;
    int fault;
    int write = error_code & PF_WRITE;
    unsigned int flags = FAULT_FLAG_ALLOW_RETRY | FAULT_FLAG_KILLABLE |
                    (write ? FAULT_FLAG_WRITE : 0);

    tsk = current;
    mm = tsk->mm;

    /* Get the faulting address: */
    address = read_cr2();

    /*
     * Detect and handle instructions that would cause a page fault for
     * both a tracked kernel page and a userspace page.
     */
    if (kmemcheck_active(regs))
        kmemcheck_hide(regs);
    prefetchw(&mm->mmap_sem);

    if (unlikely(kmmio_fault(regs, address)))
        return;
    .....
```

And this is a disassembly of the do_page_fault function from the core dump:

```
Dump of assembler code for function do_page_fault:

   0xffffffff81441c77 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0xffffffff81441c78 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0xffffffff81441c7b <+4>:     push   %r15
   0xffffffff81441c7d <+6>:     push   %r14
   0xffffffff81441c7f <+8>:     push   %r13
   0xffffffff81441c81 <+10>:    push   %r12
   0xffffffff81441c83 <+12>:    push   %rbx
   0xffffffff81441c84 <+13>:    sub    $0xd8,%rsp
   0xffffffff81441c8b <+20>:    data32 data32 data32 xchg %ax,%ax
   0xffffffff81441c90 <+25>:    mov    %esi,%eax
   0xffffffff81441c92 <+27>:    mov    %rdi,%rbx
   0xffffffff81441c95 <+30>:    mov    %rsi,%r13
   0xffffffff81441c98 <+33>:    and    $0x2,%eax
   0xffffffff81441c9b <+36>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
   0xffffffff81441c9e <+39>:    sbb    %eax,%eax
   0xffffffff81441ca0 <+41>:    add    $0x29,%eax
   0xffffffff81441ca3 <+44>:    mov    %eax,-0xe4(%rbp)
   0xffffffff81441ca9 <+50>:    mov    %gs:0xc400,%r15
   0xffffffff81441cb2 <+59>:    mov    0x270(%r15),%rax
   0xffffffff81441cb9 <+66>:    mov    %rax,-0xf0(%rbp)
   0xffffffff81441cc0 <+73>:    mov    %cr2,%rax
   0xffffffff81441cc3 <+76>:    data32 data32 xchg %ax,%ax
   0xffffffff81441cc7 <+80>:    mov    %rax,%r12
   0xffffffff81441cca <+83>:    mov    -0xf0(%rbp),%rax
   0xffffffff81441cd1 <+90>:    add    $0x60,%rax
   0xffffffff81441cd5 <+94>:    mov    %rax,-0xf8(%rbp)
   0xffffffff81441cdc <+101>:   prefetcht0 (%rax)
   0xffffffff81441cdf <+104>:   movabs $0x7fffffffefff,%rax
   0xffffffff81441ce9 <+114>:   cmp    %rax,%r12
   0xffffffff81441cec <+117>:   jbe    0xffffffff81441d50 <do_page_fault+217>
   0xffffffff81441cee <+119>:   test   $0xd,%r13b
   0xffffffff81441cf2 <+123>:   jne    0xffffffff81441d04 <do_page_fault+141>
   0xffffffff81441cf4 <+125>:   mov    %r12,%rdi
   0xffffffff81441cf7 <+128>:   callq  0xffffffff81441884 <vmalloc_fault>
   0xffffffff81441cfc <+133>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0xffffffff81441cfe <+135>:   jns    0xffffffff81441ff9 <do_page_fault+898>
   0xffffffff81441d04 <+141>:   mov    %r12,%rsi
   0xffffffff81441d07 <+144>:   mov    %r13,%rdi
   0xffffffff81441d0a <+147>:   callq  0xffffffff81441af0 <spurious_fault>
   0xffffffff81441d0f <+152>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0xffffffff81441d11 <+154>:   jne    0xffffffff81441ff9 <do_page_fault+898>
   0xffffffff81441d17 <+160>:   testb  $0x3,0x88(%rbx)
   0xffffffff81441d1e <+167>:   jne    0xffffffff81441e3e <do_page_fault+455>
   0xffffffff81441d24 <+173>:   mov    %gs:0xd4e0,%rax
   0xffffffff81441d2d <+182>:   test   %rax,%rax
   0xffffffff81441d30 <+185>:   je     0xffffffff81441e3e <do_page_fault+455>
   0xffffffff81441d36 <+191>:   mov    $0xe,%esi
   0xffffffff81441d3b <+196>:   mov    %rbx,%rdi
   0xffffffff81441d3e <+199>:   callq  0xffffffff81441253 <kprobe_fault_handler>
   0xffffffff81441d43 <+204>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0xffffffff81441d45 <+206>:   jne    0xffffffff81441ff9 <do_page_fault+898>
   0xffffffff81441d4b <+212>:   jmpq   0xffffffff81441e3e <do_page_fault+455>
   0xffffffff81441d50 <+217>:   testb  $0x3,0x88(%rbx)
      0xffffffff81441d57 <+224>:   jne    0xffffffff81441d7c <do_page_fault+261>
   0xffffffff81441d59 <+226>:   mov    %gs:0xd4e0,%rax
   0xffffffff81441d62 <+235>:   test   %rax,%rax
   0xffffffff81441d65 <+238>:   je     0xffffffff81441d7c <do_page_fault+261>
   0xffffffff81441d67 <+240>:   mov    $0xe,%esi
   0xffffffff81441d6c <+245>:   mov    %rbx,%rdi
   0xffffffff81441d6f <+248>:   callq  0xffffffff81441253 <kprobe_fault_handler>
   0xffffffff81441d74 <+253>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0xffffffff81441d76 <+255>:   jne    0xffffffff81441ff9 <do_page_fault+898>
   0xffffffff81441d7c <+261>:   testb  $0x3,0x88(%rbx)
   0xffffffff81441d83 <+268>:   je     0xffffffff81441d97 <do_page_fault+288>
   0xffffffff81441d85 <+270>:   callq  0xffffffff810be11d <trace_hardirqs_on>
   0xffffffff81441d8a <+275>:   sti    
   0xffffffff81441d8b <+276>:   data32 xchg %ax,%ax
   0xffffffff81441d8e <+279>:   data32 xchg %ax,%ax
   0xffffffff81441d91 <+282>:   or     $0x4,%r13
   0xffffffff81441d95 <+286>:   jmp    0xffffffff81441dac <do_page_fault+309>
   0xffffffff81441d97 <+288>:   testb  $0x2,0x91(%rbx)
   0xffffffff81441d9e <+295>:   je     0xffffffff81441dac <do_page_fault+309>
   0xffffffff81441da0 <+297>:   callq  0xffffffff810be11d <trace_hardirqs_on>
   0xffffffff81441da5 <+302>:   sti    
   0xffffffff81441da6 <+303>:   data32 xchg %ax,%ax
   0xffffffff81441da9 <+306>:   data32 xchg %ax,%ax
   0xffffffff81441dac <+309>:   test   $0x8,%r13b
   0xffffffff81441db0 <+313>:   je     0xffffffff81441dc0 <do_page_fault+329>
   0xffffffff81441db2 <+315>:   mov    %r12,%rdx
   0xffffffff81441db5 <+318>:   mov    %r13,%rsi
   0xffffffff81441db8 <+321>:   mov    %rbx,%rdi
   0xffffffff81441dbb <+324>:   callq  0xffffffff810369ea <pgtable_bad>
   0xffffffff81441dc0 <+329>:   mov    0x8ea4f2(%rip),%eax        # 0xffffffff81d2c2b8 <perf_swevent_enabled+8>
   0xffffffff81441dc6 <+335>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0xffffffff81441dc8 <+337>:   je     0xffffffff81441df8 <do_page_fault+385>
   0xffffffff81441dca <+339>:   test   %rbx,%rbx
   0xffffffff81441dcd <+342>:   mov    %rbx,%rcx
   0xffffffff81441dd0 <+345>:   jne    0xffffffff81441de4 <do_page_fault+365>
   0xffffffff81441dd2 <+347>:   lea    -0xe0(%rbp),%r14
   0xffffffff81441dd9 <+354>:   mov    %r14,%rdi
   0xffffffff81441ddc <+357>:   callq  0xffffffff81037284 <perf_fetch_caller_regs>
   0xffffffff81441de1 <+362>:   mov    %r14,%rcx
   0xffffffff81441de4 <+365>:   mov    %r12,%r8
   0xffffffff81441de7 <+368>:   xor    %edx,%edx
   0xffffffff81441de9 <+370>:   mov    $0x1,%esi
   0xffffffff81441dee <+375>:   mov    $0x2,%edi
   0xffffffff81441df3 <+380>:   callq  0xffffffff810d24b2 <__perf_sw_event>
   0xffffffff81441df8 <+385>:   mov    %gs:0xc408,%rax
   0xffffffff81441e01 <+394>:   testl  $0xefffffff,-0x1fbc(%rax)
   0xffffffff81441e0b <+404>:   jne    0xffffffff81441e3e <do_page_fault+455>
   0xffffffff81441e0d <+406>:   cmpq   $0x0,-0xf0(%rbp)
   0xffffffff81441e15 <+414>:   je     0xffffffff81441e3e <do_page_fault+455>
   0xffffffff81441e17 <+416>:   mov    -0xf8(%rbp),%rdi
   0xffffffff81441e1e <+423>:   callq  0xffffffff810721e4 <down_read_trylock>
   0xffffffff81441e23 <+428>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0xffffffff81441e25 <+430>:   jne    0xffffffff81441e5d <do_page_fault+486>
   0xffffffff81441e27 <+432>:   test   $0x4,%r13b
   0xffffffff81441e2b <+436>:   jne    0xffffffff81441e51 <do_page_fault+474>
   0xffffffff81441e2d <+438>:   mov    0x80(%rbx),%rdi
   0xffffffff81441e34 <+445>:   callq  0xffffffff8106bb2c <search_exception_tables>
   0xffffffff81441e39 <+450>:   test   %rax,%rax
   0xffffffff81441e3c <+453>:   jne    0xffffffff81441e51 <do_page_fault+474>
   0xffffffff81441e3e <+455>:   mov    %r12,%rdx
   0xffffffff81441e41 <+458>:   mov    %r13,%rsi
   0xffffffff81441e44 <+461>:   mov    %rbx,%rdi
   0xffffffff81441e47 <+464>:   callq  0xffffffff8103707e <bad_area_nosemaphore>
   0xffffffff81441e4c <+469>:   jmpq   0xffffffff81441ff9 <do_page_fault+898>
   0xffffffff81441e51 <+474>:   mov    -0xf8(%rbp),%rdi
   0xffffffff81441e58 <+481>:   callq  0xffffffff8143def4 <down_read>
   0xffffffff81441e5d <+486>:   mov    -0xf0(%rbp),%rdi
   0xffffffff81441e64 <+493>:   mov    %r12,%rsi
   0xffffffff81441e67 <+496>:   callq  0xffffffff810f62eb <find_vma>
   0xffffffff81441e6c <+501>:   test   %rax,%rax
   0xffffffff81441e6f <+504>:   mov    %rax,%r14
   0xffffffff81441e72 <+507>:   je     0xffffffff81441ea6 <do_page_fault+559>
   0xffffffff81441e74 <+509>:   cmp    %r12,0x8(%rax)
   0xffffffff81441e78 <+513>:   jbe    0xffffffff81441eb9 <do_page_fault+578>
   0xffffffff81441e7a <+515>:   testb  $0x1,0x31(%rax)
   0xffffffff81441e7e <+519>:   je     0xffffffff81441ea6 <do_page_fault+559>
   0xffffffff81441e80 <+521>:   test   $0x4,%r13b
   0xffffffff81441e84 <+525>:   je     0xffffffff81441e97 <do_page_fault+544>
   0xffffffff81441e86 <+527>:   lea    0x10100(%r12),%rax
   0xffffffff81441e8e <+535>:   cmp    0x98(%rbx),%rax
   0xffffffff81441e95 <+542>:   jb     0xffffffff81441ea6 <do_page_fault+559>
   0xffffffff81441e97 <+544>:   mov    %r12,%rsi
   0xffffffff81441e9a <+547>:   mov    %r14,%rdi
   0xffffffff81441e9d <+550>:   callq  0xffffffff810f6ce9 <expand_stack>
   0xffffffff81441ea2 <+555>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0xffffffff81441ea4 <+557>:   je     0xffffffff81441eb9 <do_page_fault+578>
   0xffffffff81441ea6 <+559>:   mov    %r12,%rdx
   0xffffffff81441ea9 <+562>:   mov    %r13,%rsi
   0xffffffff81441eac <+565>:   mov    %rbx,%rdi
   0xffffffff81441eaf <+568>:   callq  0xffffffff81037093 <bad_area>
   0xffffffff81441eb4 <+573>:   jmpq   0xffffffff81441ff9 <do_page_fault+898>
   0xffffffff81441eb9 <+578>:   test   $0x2,%r13b
   0xffffffff81441ebd <+582>:   je     0xffffffff81441ec6 <do_page_fault+591>
   0xffffffff81441ebf <+584>:   testb  $0x2,0x30(%r14)
   0xffffffff81441ec4 <+589>:   jmp    0xffffffff81441ed1 <do_page_fault+602>
   0xffffffff81441ec6 <+591>:   test   $0x1,%r13b
   0xffffffff81441eca <+595>:   jne    0xffffffff81441ed7 <do_page_fault+608>
   0xffffffff81441ecc <+597>:   testb  $0x7,0x30(%r14)
   0xffffffff81441ed1 <+602>:   jne    0xffffffff81441fce <do_page_fault+855>
   0xffffffff81441ed7 <+608>:   mov    %r12,%rdx
   0xffffffff81441eda <+611>:   mov    %r13,%rsi
   0xffffffff81441edd <+614>:   mov    %rbx,%rdi
   0xffffffff81441ee0 <+617>:   callq  0xffffffff810370e1 <bad_area_access_error>
   0xffffffff81441ee5 <+622>:   jmpq   0xffffffff81441ff9 <do_page_fault+898>
   0xffffffff81441eea <+627>:   mov    %r14d,%ecx
   0xffffffff81441eed <+630>:   mov    %r12,%rdx
   0xffffffff81441ef0 <+633>:   mov    %r13,%rsi
   0xffffffff81441ef3 <+636>:   mov    %rbx,%rdi
   0xffffffff81441ef6 <+639>:   callq  0xffffffff8103712f <mm_fault_error>
   0xffffffff81441efb <+644>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0xffffffff81441efd <+646>:   jne    0xffffffff81441ff9 <do_page_fault+898>
   0xffffffff81441f03 <+652>:   testb  $0x8,-0xe4(%rbp)
   0xffffffff81441f0a <+659>:   je     0xffffffff81441fc0 <do_page_fault+841>
   0xffffffff81441f10 <+665>:   test   $0x4,%r14b
   0xffffffff81441f14 <+669>:   je     0xffffffff81441f61 <do_page_fault+746>
   0xffffffff81441f16 <+671>:   incq   0x3f8(%r15)
   0xffffffff81441f1d <+678>:   mov    0x8ea3a5(%rip),%eax        # 0xffffffff81d2c2c8 <perf_swevent_enabled+24>
   0xffffffff81441f23 <+684>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0xffffffff81441f25 <+686>:   je     0xffffffff81441fab <do_page_fault+820>
   0xffffffff81441f2b <+692>:   test   %rbx,%rbx
   0xffffffff81441f2e <+695>:   mov    %rbx,%rcx
   0xffffffff81441f31 <+698>:   jne    0xffffffff81441f50 <do_page_fault+729>
   0xffffffff81441f33 <+700>:   lea    -0xe0(%rbp),%rcx
   0xffffffff81441f3a <+707>:   mov    %rcx,%rdi
   0xffffffff81441f3d <+710>:   mov    %rcx,-0x100(%rbp)
   0xffffffff81441f44 <+717>:   callq  0xffffffff81037284 <perf_fetch_caller_regs>
   0xffffffff81441f49 <+722>:   mov    -0x100(%rbp),%rcx
   0xffffffff81441f50 <+729>:   mov    %r12,%r8
   0xffffffff81441f53 <+732>:   xor    %edx,%edx
   0xffffffff81441f55 <+734>:   mov    $0x1,%esi
   0xffffffff81441f5a <+739>:   mov    $0x6,%edi
   0xffffffff81441f5f <+744>:   jmp    0xffffffff81441fa6 <do_page_fault+815>
   0xffffffff81441f61 <+746>:   incq   0x3f0(%r15)
   0xffffffff81441f68 <+753>:   mov    0x8ea356(%rip),%eax        # 0xffffffff81d2c2c4 <perf_swevent_enabled+20>
   0xffffffff81441f6e <+759>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0xffffffff81441f70 <+761>:   je     0xffffffff81441fab <do_page_fault+820>
   0xffffffff81441f72 <+763>:   test   %rbx,%rbx
   0xffffffff81441f75 <+766>:   mov    %rbx,%rcx
   0xffffffff81441f78 <+769>:   jne    0xffffffff81441f97 <do_page_fault+800>
   0xffffffff81441f7a <+771>:   lea    -0xe0(%rbp),%rcx
   0xffffffff81441f81 <+778>:   mov    %rcx,%rdi
   0xffffffff81441f84 <+781>:   mov    %rcx,-0x100(%rbp)
   0xffffffff81441f8b <+788>:   callq  0xffffffff81037284 <perf_fetch_caller_regs>
   0xffffffff81441f90 <+793>:   mov    -0x100(%rbp),%rcx
   0xffffffff81441f97 <+800>:   mov    %r12,%r8
   0xffffffff81441f9a <+803>:   xor    %edx,%edx
   0xffffffff81441f9c <+805>:   mov    $0x1,%esi
   0xffffffff81441fa1 <+810>:   mov    $0x5,%edi
   0xffffffff81441fa6 <+815>:   callq  0xffffffff810d24b2 <__perf_sw_event>
   0xffffffff81441fab <+820>:   and    $0x400,%r14d
   0xffffffff81441fb2 <+827>:   je     0xffffffff81441fc0 <do_page_fault+841>
   0xffffffff81441fb4 <+829>:   andl   $0xfffffff7,-0xe4(%rbp)
   0xffffffff81441fbb <+836>:   jmpq   0xffffffff81441e51 <do_page_fault+474>
   0xffffffff81441fc0 <+841>:   mov    -0xf8(%rbp),%rdi
   0xffffffff81441fc7 <+848>:   callq  0xffffffff8107222e <up_read>
   0xffffffff81441fcc <+853>:   jmp    0xffffffff81441ff9 <do_page_fault+898>
   0xffffffff81441fce <+855>:   mov    -0xe4(%rbp),%ecx
   0xffffffff81441fd4 <+861>:   mov    -0xf0(%rbp),%rdi
   0xffffffff81441fdb <+868>:   mov    %r14,%rsi
   0xffffffff81441fde <+871>:   mov    %r12,%rdx
   0xffffffff81441fe1 <+874>:   callq  0xffffffff810f45bf <handle_mm_fault>
   0xffffffff81441fe6 <+879>:   test   $0x433,%eax
   0xffffffff81441feb <+884>:   mov    %eax,%r14d
   0xffffffff81441fee <+887>:   je     0xffffffff81441f03 <do_page_fault+652>
   0xffffffff81441ff4 <+893>:   jmpq   0xffffffff81441eea <do_page_fault+627>
   0xffffffff81441ff9 <+898>:   add    $0xd8,%rsp
   0xffffffff81442000 <+905>:   pop    %rbx
   0xffffffff81442001 <+906>:   pop    %r12
   0xffffffff81442003 <+908>:   pop    %r13
   0xffffffff81442005 <+910>:   pop    %r14
   0xffffffff81442007 <+912>:   pop    %r15
   0xffffffff81442009 <+914>:   leaveq 
   0xffffffff8144200a <+915>:   retq
```

Now, is it possible to find out what is the address of the page fault? where is it stored on the function's stack?

**UPDATE:**

here is the output if bt -f

```
#0 [ffff8801f01159f0] __schedule at ffffffff8143d229
    ffff8801f01159f8: 0000000000000082 ffff8801f1201818 
    ffff8801f0115a08: ffff880100000000 ffff8801f0114010 
    ffff8801f0115a18: ffff8801b9880780 0000000000011b80 
    ffff8801f0115a28: ffff8801f0115fd8 ffff8801f0115fd8 
    ffff8801f0115a38: 0000000000011b80 ffff8801f19264c0 
    ffff8801f0115a48: ffff8801b9880780 ffffffff810f3f7b 
    ffff8801f0115a58: 00000001b74d4828 ffffea00b74d4860 
    ffff8801f0115a68: ffff8801f15fa5a0 ffff8801b9880780 
    ffff8801f0115a78: 0000000000000001 fffffffeffffffff 
    ffff8801f0115a88: ffff8801b9880780 ffff8801f0115aa0 
    ffff8801f0115a98: ffffffff8143d3b5 
 #1 [ffff8801f0115a98] schedule at ffffffff8143d3b5
    ffff8801f0115aa0: ffff8801f0115b00 ffffffff8143e7ed 
 #2 [ffff8801f0115aa8] rwsem_down_failed_common at ffffffff8143e7ed
    ffff8801f0115ab0: ffff8801f15fa5b0 ffff8801f15fa5b0 
    ffff8801f0115ac0: 0000000000000000 00007fea00000001 
    ffff8801f0115ad0: 80000001ed0c0067 0000000000000000 
    ffff8801f0115ae0: ffff8801f0115c88 00007fea45ccbfe7 
    ffff8801f0115af0: 0000000000000002 0000000000000000 
    ffff8801f0115b00: ffff8801f0115b10 ffffffff8143e846 
 #3 [ffff8801f0115b08] rwsem_down_read_failed at ffffffff8143e846
    ffff8801f0115b10: ffff8801f0115b68 ffffffff812166c4 
 #4 [ffff8801f0115b18] call_rwsem_down_read_failed at ffffffff812166c4
    ffff8801f0115b20: ffffffff81120c26 0000000000000ff8 
    ffff8801f0115b30: 0000000000000000 0000000000000004 
    ffff8801f0115b40: 00007fea45ccbfe7 ffff8801f1201818 
    ffff8801f0115b50: ffffffff8144afe0 ffff8801f15fa5a0 
    ffff8801f0115b60: ffffffff8143df0b ffff8801f0115c78 
    ffff8801f0115b70: ffffffff81441e5d 
 #5 [ffff8801f0115b70] do_page_fault at ffffffff81441e5d
    ffff8801f0115b78: ffff8801f0115ba8 ffff8801f15fa5a0 
    ffff8801f0115b88: ffff8801f15fa540 00000029811333a0 
    ffff8801f0115b98: ffff8801f0115bb8 ffff8801eff11940 
    ffff8801f0115ba8: 0000000000000068 ffff8802d3001080 
    ffff8801f0115bb8: 00000000000000d0 00000000000000d0 
    ffff8801f0115bc8: ffff8801f0115c18 ffffffff8110ecc5 
    ffff8801f0115bd8: 0000000000000020 0000000200000202 
    ffff8801f0115be8: 00000000000000d0 0000000000000002 
    ffff8801f0115bf8: ffff8802d3ad4aa0 0000000000000002 
    ffff8801f0115c08: ffffea0009e3b150 ffffea0009e3b128 
    ffff8801f0115c18: ffff8801f0115c98 ffff8801f0115de8 
    ffff8801f0115c28: ffffffff812167ca 0000000000000ff8 
    ffff8801f0115c38: 0000000000000000 0000000000000004 
    ffff8801f0115c48: 00007fea45ccbfe7 0000000000000001 
    ffff8801f0115c58: ffff8801a41b8078 0000000000000ff8 
    ffff8801f0115c68: 0000000000000000 0000000000002ff0 
    ffff8801f0115c78: ffff8801f0115de8 ffffffff8143f105 
 #6 [ffff8801f0115c80] page_fault at ffffffff8143f105
    [exception RIP: pipe_read+324]
    RIP: ffffffff81120c26  RSP: ffff8801f0115d38  RFLAGS: 00010206
    RAX: ffff8801f0115ec8  RBX: ffff8801ba6bcd40  RCX: 0000000000000000
    RDX: 0000000000000ff8  RSI: 0000000000001017  RDI: 0000000000000ff8
    RBP: ffff8801f0115de8   R8: 00007fea45ccbfe7   R9: 0000000000000004
    R10: 0000000000000000  R11: 0000000000000ff8  R12: ffff8801a41b8078
    R13: 0000000000000ff8  R14: 0000000000000000  R15: 0000000000002ff0
 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
    ffff8801f0115c88: 0000000000002ff0 0000000000000000 
    ffff8801f0115c98: 0000000000000ff8 ffff8801a41b8078 
    ffff8801f0115ca8: ffff8801f0115de8 ffff8801ba6bcd40 
    ffff8801f0115cb8: 0000000000000ff8 0000000000000000 
    ffff8801f0115cc8: 0000000000000004 00007fea45ccbfe7 
    ffff8801f0115cd8: ffff8801f0115ec8 0000000000000000 
    ffff8801f0115ce8: 0000000000000ff8 0000000000001017 
    ffff8801f0115cf8: 0000000000000ff8 ffffffffffffffff 
    ffff8801f0115d08: ffffffff81120c26 0000000000000010 
    ffff8801f0115d18: 0000000000010206 ffff8801f0115d38 
    ffff8801f0115d28: 0000000000000018 ffffffff81120bb8 
    ffff8801f0115d38: ffffffff81211ef8 ffff8801b9880780 
    ffff8801f0115d48: 0000000000001ff8 ffff8801ef41e390 
    ffff8801f0115d58: ffff8801ba6bcd88 00000003f12012d0 
    ffff8801f0115d68: ffff8801ba582000 ffff8801f0115ec8 
    ffff8801f0115d78: 00000001f0115dc8 ffffffff81617180 
    ffff8801f0115d88: 00000001f0115dc8 ffff8801ba582ff8 
    ffff8801f0115d98: 0000000df0115da8 0000000000000ff8 
    ffff8801f0115da8: ffff8801f1508500 000000000003d010 
    ffff8801f0115db8: 0000000000100073 ffff8801f0115df8 
    ffff8801f0115dc8: ffff8801f0115f58 ffff8801f1508500 
    ffff8801f0115dd8: ffff8801f0115ec8 0000000000000003 
    ffff8801f0115de8: ffff8801f0115ef8 ffffffff81118dfe 
 #7 [ffff8801f0115df0] do_sync_read at ffffffff81118dfe
    ffff8801f0115df8: 0000000000011b80 0000000000000000 
    ffff8801f0115e08: 0000000000000000 ffffffff00000001 
    ffff8801f0115e18: ffff8801f1508500 0000000000000000 
    ffff8801f0115e28: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 
    ffff8801f0115e38: 0000000000000000 ffff8801b9880780 
    ffff8801f0115e48: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 
    ffff8801f0115e58: 0000000000000000 ffff8801ef41e358 
    ffff8801f0115e68: 0000000000040000 0000000000000003 
    ffff8801f0115e78: 0000000000040000 ffffffff811e4d73 
    ffff8801f0115e88: ffff8801f0115ef8 ffff8801f1508500 
    ffff8801f0115e98: 0000000000000004 0000000000000000 
    ffff8801f0115ea8: ffff8801f0115ec8 ffffffff811e4de0 
    ffff8801f0115eb8: 0000000000040000 ffff8801f1508500 
    ffff8801f0115ec8: 00007fea45ccaff0 000000000003d010 
    ffff8801f0115ed8: ffff8801f1508500 00007fea45cc8000 
    ffff8801f0115ee8: ffff8801f0115f58 0000000000040000 
    ffff8801f0115ef8: ffff8801f0115f38 ffffffff8111988f 
 #8 [ffff8801f0115f00] vfs_read at ffffffff8111988f
    ffff8801f0115f08: 0000000000000001 00007fea43ceb000 
    ffff8801f0115f18: 0000000000000003 ffff8801f1508500 
    ffff8801f0115f28: 00007fea45cc8000 00007fea45cc8000 
    ffff8801f0115f38: ffff8801f0115f78 ffffffff811199ae 
 #9 [ffff8801f0115f40] sys_read at ffffffff811199ae
    ffff8801f0115f48: 0000000000000000 0000000000040000 
    ffff8801f0115f58: 0000000000000000 00000001f0114000 
    ffff8801f0115f68: 0000003dcdd8e6c0 0000000000040000 
    ffff8801f0115f78: 0000000000000000 ffffffff81445742 
#10 [ffff8801f0115f80] system_call_fastpath at ffffffff81445742
    RIP: 0000003dcdadb51d  RSP: 00007fea454ed0d0  RFLAGS: 00003246
    RAX: 0000000000000000  RBX: ffffffff81445742  RCX: 00007fea4907b088
    RDX: 0000000000040000  RSI: 00007fea45cc8000  RDI: 0000000000000000
    RBP: 0000000000000000   R8: 00000000ffffffff   R9: 0000000000000000
    R10: 0000000000000022  R11: 0000000000003293  R12: 0000000000040000
    R13: 0000003dcdd8e6c0  R14: 00000001f0114000  R15: 0000000000000000
    ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000000  CS: 0033  SS: 002b
```

Comment: It's not stored anywhere in memory, at least not in the partial disassembly you've shown. It's stored in R12. If `do_page_fault` isn't the active function at the time of the crash, then you'd have to unwind the stack to see where it might have been saved. If your crash utility can't do this for you then you'll need to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

The faulting address is very likely of little to no significance. All necessary data should be visible "around" the stack frame.

What is the context here? Did you get a panic from hung task detector with a thread waiting to get the semaphore? As in, are you sure you are looking at the right thread here?

While I can't verify now, afair the address is obtainable from the register dump you can see when you 'bt'. Alternatively, as the commenter noted the address lands in r12. Chances are further assembly moves it around, but otherwise it should be in that register OR pushed to the stack if a function is called. Computing its location is left as an exercise for the reader, it is only mildly cumbersome. In fact, 'bt -f' will likely make the address easily stand out without much analysis. If not, you can 'dis -r' on the return address to disassembly upwards from that part.

Chances are what you are looking at is a classic: a nfs-based mmapped file, where the server is not responding. Notes of a not responding server will be seen in dmesg, but mere bt should tell you it is waiting for something.

**Now the update.**

The bt as posted clearly shows this very thread got 'stuck' for some time waiting for the lock owner. So what you should investigate is the lock owner, as opposed to this thread. The pointer to the owner should be stored somewhere in the semaphore in relatively recent kernels. For super old kernels (and it seems you are running one), you may need to resort to investigating all traces.

As a side note, it is not hard to spot a userspace-y address in the dump: 00007fea45ccbfe7

Looking at arguments passed to the read system call, we see rsi 00007fea45cc8000 (the passed buffer) and rdx 0000000000040000. That is, the address definitely belongs to the buffer, but the offset for a page fault is somewhat odd. You would have to disassemble to confirm. However, as noted earlier, this is the wrong thread to look at in the first place.

Comment: 1) I modified some of memory management code. So, I want to know if that address falls into my managed memory area. 2) Yes, I got it from a hung task panic. 3) I will try the other things you mentioned.

Comment: I will post the output of 'bt -f' above.